# STL approaches for given loop

Tags: c++

this loop works fine as expected. however is there any STL approach to mimic the exact functionality as the example below?

```
for (auto i = vec.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    vec[i] = vec[i - 1];
}
```

Comment: Wait before the downvotes start dropping, why would you ever need to do this/what does this even do, my brain is blanking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than an insertion or a rotate, all we're doing here is copying, so it seems like the thing to use is a copy. We could do the job with `reverse_iterators`:

```
std::copy(f.rbegin() + 1, f.rend(), f.rbegin());
```

...or with the algorithm really intended specifically for this sort of situation, `std::copy_backward`:

```
std::copy_backward(f.begin(), f.end()-1, f.end());
```

Either way, it's simple, straightforward, and about as efficient as possible (almost certainly more efficient than using insert/pop or rotate/assign).

Answer (score 3):

`std::rotate`:

```
template< class ForwardIt >
ForwardIt rotate( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last );
```

Used as (for a vector `v`)

```
// rotation left
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end());

// example:
// initial v:      1 2 3 4 5
// after rotate: : 2 3 4 5 1

// rotation right (as in your "script")
std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());

// example:
// initial v:      1 2 3 4 5
// after rotate:   5 1 2 3 4

//now if you do this,then it'll have the same effect as your code.
v[0] = v[1];
//before assignment: 5 1 2 3 4
//after  assignment: 1 1 2 3 4
```

The difference w.r.t. your example is that, here, the first element will receive the previously last element (whereas in your code, the first element is untouched).

> Performs a left rotation on a range of elements.
>
> Specifically, `std::rotate` swaps the elements in the range [first,
>   last) in such a way that the element n_first becomes the first element
>   of the new range and n_first - 1 becomes the last element.
>
> A precondition of this function is that [first, n_first) and [n_first,
>   last) are valid ranges.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: @MORTAL: `std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());`.. followed by `v[0] = v[1];` would do the exact thing as in your code.

Comment: @Nawaz .. yes it works also this way. which one is most efficient.

Comment: @MORTAL: This one is more efficient, as the other one (which does add/remove) might result in reallocation which is surely a slower operation. I personally, would have preferred `std::rotate`  followed by a single assignment over `erase/push_back/insert/pop_back` approach.

Answer (score 2):

The *exact* equivalent? Assuming the `vector` is not empty:

```
auto val = vec.front(); //Just in case the list is 1 element long.
vec.pop_back();
vec.insert(vec.begin(), val);
```

Your code effectively does this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

The first element is in two places, while the last element is lost. The above code does the same.

Comment: This may be more efficient if you do the `pop_back()` first to prevent the possibility of reallocation.

Comment: The `std::rotate` followed by a single assignment is far superior!

Comment: @Galik: And it'll blow up if the `vec` is only one element long. So you have to do more than just swap where the `pop_back` is.